# Is there a way to make multiple queries apply a filter based on a single set of values?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

Currently I have a bunch of queries set up on our Cognos BI-suite that have exactly the same filter applied and unfortunately the content of that filter changes fairly often. This concurrently means that I have to manually update filters on 10+ reports by hand on a weekly basis.

Is there any way to make this more efficient by having a single set list somewhere and then having the queries pull their filter content from the list whenever they run?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is having to change filter content (for example, a hard-coded string value) then the easiest way to make this more maintainable is to create a filter object in the model. If you do this, then you can use the filter in your report and the definition stays in the model.

For example, imagine a filter like this:

```
[Department] = 'Food'
```

You can create a filter object in the model called 'Department' or something more descriptive with the expression above. When you need that filter to apply to a report, you simply drag in the filter object in the model.

Later, if you need to change the filter, you only have to do it once in the model and it will automatically apply in all reports that reference that filter.